# General query about efficiency

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to Java, having taken my first class in it little under a year ago, and I have a question regarding efficiency. I know that

```
Random rng = new Random();
int num = rng.nextInt(101);
System.out.println("Random number is: " + num); //Example 1
```

and

```
Random rng = new Random();
System.out.println("Random number is: " + rng.nextInt(101)); //Example 2
```

are equivalent. However my question is which is faster to calculate? In my mind, the first example stores a variable, which takes up RAM. The second example doesn't store anything, but has to calculate a lot more things whilst printing than the first example.

In my computing classes, I was taught that information coming from the CPU's internal registers is a lot faster than information coming from the RAM. Does that mean example 2 is technically more efficient for not having stored the number variable before printing it?

I'm of course assuming I will not need the randomly generated number at another point in the program.

Thank you for any and all help :)
Kind regards

Comment: No, these are going to be identical in performance.  _Stop messing with little details like this._  (And what makes you think local variables won't get stored in CPU registers?)

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I assumed because you're actively creating a variable, and storing it that it would be sent to the RAM. Just in case it needed to be called later. At the time of use, I'm sure it would be in the register, but I was wondering about before that. Sorry for the confusion, and thank you for the information!

Comment: dont even _try_ to think about efficiency just yet - except for _extreme_ inefficiency there is no need to optimize anything; under no circumstance. In fact, many program errors happen because of faulty optimization-attempts. At first, you will need to learn about _functionality_ at every level, even if that means writing inefficient code -- inefficiency can be fixed at any time, missing features or broken parts sometimes prove to be showstoppers

Comment: @specializt Good point, and thanks for the info! :) Was more of a question I had in my mind when I was writing some code, wondered if it was wasting resources by assigning a variable when I could do it the way it's done in example 2. I knew it wouldn't make a lot of different, if any, seeing as most primitives are 32-bits in size, but I wanted to learn to do things correctly, if at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any sane compiler will be able to perform such compile time optimizations to reduce extra lines of code which are there to improve readability.That is not specific to Java(where JIT takes the optimizations to the next level)

Comment: would you mind elaborating on the "taking optimizations to the next level" claim? I think there might be a misconception hidden underneath your perception of Java and JIT ....

Comment: next level here refers to runtime...Rather than having any concepts/mis-concepts myself about JIT optimizations i would refer the docs

Comment: JIT and JIT optimizations are not exclusive to Java, not even remotely. Your second statement doesnt make any sense.

Comment: from which statement do u conclude JIT is specific to Java..vice versa doesn't apply everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Since the number is going to be converted to a String for the concatenation, it will probably be put in memory on the stack anyways.